# Jackson Builder Pattern causes message Body Reader not found

Tags: java, glassfish, jackson, builder

I am attempting to use the `@JsonDeserialize(builder = class)` annotation example for Jackson to allow for the builder pattern. I tried to use my objects but kept running into an error. I then copied this example from the Jackson webpage, but it is still not working.
Here is my sample files:

Data Item

```
package org.cpicard.finance;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonDeserialize(builder=ExampleBuilder.class)
public class Example {
   private final int x, y;
   protected Example(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}
```

Builder

```
package org.cpicard.finance;
public class ExampleBuilder {
   private int x, y;
   public ExampleBuilder () { }

   public ExampleBuilder withX(int x) {
      this.x = x;
      return this;
   }
   public ExampleBuilder withY(int y) {
      this.y = y;
      return this;
   }

   public Example build() {
      return new Example(x, y);
   }
}
```

Rest Service

```
package org.cpicard.finance;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.cpicard.model.finance.Example;

@Path("/account")
public class AccountService {

   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Path("test1")
   public Response createAccount1(final Example account) {
      System.out.println(account.toString());
      return Response.ok().build();
   }
}
```

Application Config

```
package org.cpicard.finance;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rs")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

   private final Set<Class<?>> classes;

   public ApplicationConfig() {
      final HashSet<Class<?>> c = new HashSet<>();
      c.add(AccountService.class);

      classes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(c);
   }

   @Override
   public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
      return classes;
   }
}
```

Web xml Snippet

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cpicard.finance.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This results in the following error:

> [2015-03-01T10:30:19.576-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] []
>   [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor]
>   [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis:
>   1425231019576] [levelValue: 1000] [[   MessageBodyReader not found for
>   media type=application/json, type=class
>   org.cpicard.model.finance.Example, genericType=class
>   org.cpicard.model.finance.Example.]]

When I switch the data item to a standard object that has regular getters and setters it works fine. I am thinking there is something incorrect in my configuration, but not sure what it could be.

Using Glassfish 4.1

Comment: Is there a typo in the pasted code: `protected Dummy(int x, int y)` should be `protected Example(int x, int y)` in class Example?

Comment: Yes that is a typo, originally I was calling the example class dummy, but I changed it to example. The constructor is protected Example(int x, int y) in my project.